# Double integral of $x+y^2$ for $y=x$ and $y^2=x$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Hello I'm new to double integrals and have only solved one yet, but I'm stuck, not with the integral itself but with the upper/lower limits.

I need to find the double integral of $x+y^2$ for $A: $ $y=x$ and $y^2=x$

How can I find my upper and lower limit from $A$?

Comment: Step -1 is to write down a meaningful description of the region $A$ (you have not done that yet).  Step 0 is to draw a picture of the region $A$.  Step 0.5 is to look at your textbook and find a similar example and study how it was done in that example.  Step 1 is to decide whether to use horizontal or vertical slices.

Comment: Okay, I will do that and I have found that the region of A lies between $0\le x\le 1\:$ and $0\le y\le 1\:$ is that a better description for my region A?

Comment: Your region is *contained in* the square $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $0 \leq y \leq 1$, but it is only a small portion of that square.  Please, go read your notes or textbook and carefully review a detailed example or three.

Comment: Okay thank you for the help, I will go look at some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You start by making a sketch of the two given curves, $y=x$ and $y=\sqrt x$.[image]

The integration area is bounded by the blue and red curves. The two intersect at $(0,0)$ and at $(1,1)$. You have two options:

1. write integral of $x$ from $0$ to $1$ and write the lower and upper limit in terms of $x$
   $$\int_0^1 dx\int_x^{\sqrt x} dy (x+y^2)$$
2. write integral of $y$ from $0$ to $1$ and write the lower and upper limit in terms of $y$. Then the lower $x$ is the red curve:
   $$\int_0^1 dy\int_{y^2}^y dx (x+y^2)$$

Comment: Okay, this does make more sense but would $\int _0^1\:\int _0^1\left(x+y²\right)dxdy\:$ also work or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It is wrong. You are specifically told that you integrate **only** between the two curves. your integration range suggest that you integrate in the square $(0,0)\to(0,1)\to(1,1)\to(1,0)$